# Laravel chained Eloquent Query can't return result array

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a chained Eloquent query on Laravel and bring the users from a users table with a conditional and that is, if they belong to determined house. I am struggling a little to find the way to get that to work. Can someone help me?

This is my controller method:

```
public function create(){

        if(Auth::user()->role->id == 1){

            $house = House::findOrFail(Auth::user()->house->id);

            $jobs = Job::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
            $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
            $users = User::pluck('name', 'id')->where('house_id', $house)->get();

            return view('admin.tasks.create', compact('jobs', 'categories', 'users'));

        }else{

            return redirect('home');

        }

    }
```

The error been thrown to me when using the get() is:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Housing_around/app/Http/Controllers/AdminTasksController.php on line 55 and at least 1 expected
```

And as thought, the `all()` in the end doesnt bring me anything in the returned array

Does someone have a clue on how to proceed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion I would give you is to use policies to determine roles for the current authenticated user. 
If you think that this method in your controller its handling authorization, fetching data from database and passing them to the view.

When the controller role its just a bridge between models(data structure) and presentation (views)

Check out [Laravel authorization.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization)

Then `pluck()` method its a method that under the hood it calls `get()` so you cant call them both at the same time. Same for `all()` vs `get()` all has get method calling behind the scenes.

So do like `$users = User::where('house_id', $house)->pluck('name', 'id');`

Comment: I'm used to Codeigniter and pure php that you have to make it yourself. Im very new to Laravel. Thank you all guys for the help.

Comment: Now i am having another problem:               Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Housing_around/resources/views/admin/tasks/create.blade.php).     Do you guys know what it is related to?

Answer (score 3):

Use the correct syntax to avoid the error:

```
$jobs = Job::pluck('name', 'id');
$categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
$users = User::where('house_id', $house)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `get()` after [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck)

```
$jobs = Job::pluck('name', 'id');
$categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
$users = User::where('house_id', $house)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Comment: Now i am having another problem: Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Housing_around/resources/views/admin/tasks/create.blade.php). Do you guys know what it is related to?

Comment: @LuizWynne include your view code, then we may help you